# Fitting a Normal distribution to 1D data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a 1 dimensional array. I can compute the "mean" and "standard deviation" of this sample and plot the "Normal distribution" but I have a problem:

I want to plot the data and Normal distribution in the same figure.

I dont know how to plot both the data and the normal distribution.

Any Idea about "Gaussian probability density function in scipy.stats"?

```
s = np.std(array)
m = np.mean(array)
plt.plot(norm.pdf(array,m,s))
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Please post the code you have so far so we can answer specific questions about it.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib` to plot the histogram and the PDF (as in the link in @MrE's answer).  For fitting and for computing the PDF, you can use `scipy.stats.norm`, as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Generate some data for this demonstration.
data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)

# Fit a normal distribution to the data:
mu, std = norm.fit(data)

# Plot the histogram.
plt.hist(data, bins=25, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')

# Plot the PDF.
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
plt.title(title)

plt.show()
```

Here's the plot generated by the script:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Is it possible to do this without scipy module?

Comment: @maro Yes.  Fitting the normal distribution is pretty simple. You can replace `mu, std = norm.fit(data)` with `mu = np.mean(data); std = np.std(data)`.  You'll have to implement your own version of the PDF of the normal distribution if you want to plot that curve in the figure.

Comment: Is there a reason why use `x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)` instead of `x = np.sort(data)`? The latter seems more reasonable.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀, the original data might be sparse in some areas and dense in others, making the plot of the PDF jagged.  By using linspace, you can sample the PDF on a regularly spaced grid and make the samples as dense as you like, resulting in a nice smooth plot of the PDF.

Answer (score 13):

A simple alternative it to use `seaborn` (<= 0.11.2):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm

# Generate simulated data
n_samples = 100
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
data = rng.standard_normal(n_samples)

# Fit Gaussian distribution and plot
sns.distplot(data, fit=norm, kde=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

To see both the normal distribution and your actual data you should plot your data as a histogram, then draw the probability density function over this. See the example on
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html for exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to do it using **seaborn**:

```
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm

data = norm.rvs(5,0.4,size=1000) # you can use a pandas series or a list if you want

sns.distplot(data)
plt.show()
```

[output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W208v.png)

[image]

*for more information*:[seaborn.distplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)

Comment: This is not a normal distribution. this is KDE (kernel density estimation) method