# Creating a normal distribution curve over a frequency histogram

Tags: python, scipy, histogram, normal-distribution, frequency-distribution

I have generated 10000 normally distributed random test scores as a percentage. This data is represented in a histogram that measures score percentage in the x-axis, and score frequency in the y-axis.

I want to create a normal distribution curve over the histogram with the mean and standard deviation used in the histogram. However, I'm not sure which `scipy.stats.norm` methods to use to map the curve according to frequency rather than frequency density:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

mu = 55        #mean of the data 
sigma = 10     #standard deviation of data
num_bins = 100 #number of bins used 

#generate 10k random test scores normally distributed 
nums = [int(np.random.normal(mu, sigma)) for i in range(10000)] 

#plot histogram using this data
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(nums, num_bins, density = False) 

plt.style.use('seaborn') 
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 8)
plt.xlabel('Score %')
plt.ylabel('Score Frequency')
plt.title('Histogram of Test Scores: $\mu=55$, $\sigma=10$')
```

This code produces the following
[frequency distribution histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uli0i.png)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011122/fitting-a-normal-distribution-to-1d-data/20012350#20012350