# Plot normal distribution over histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to python and in the following code, I would like to plot a bell curve to show how the data follows a norm distribution. How would I go about it? Also, can anyone answer why when showing the hist, I have values (x-axis) greater than 100? I would assume by defining the Randels to 100, it would not show anything above it. If I am not mistaken, the x-axis represents what "floor" I am in and the y-axis represents how many observations matched that floor. By the way, this is a datacamp project.

```
"""
Let's say I roll a dice to determine if I go up or down a step in a building with
100 floors (1 step = 1 floor). If the dice is less than 2, I go down a step. If 
the dice is less than or equal to 5, I go up a step, and if the dice is equal to 6,
I go up x steps based on a random integer generator between 1 and 6. What is the probability
I will be higher than floor 60?
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set the seed
np.random.seed(123)

# Simulate random walk 
all_walks = []
for i in range(1000) :
    random_walk = [0]
    for x in range(100) :
        step = random_walk[-1]
        dice = np.random.randint(1,7)
        if dice <= 2:
            step = max(0, step - 1)
        elif dice <= 5:
            step = step + 1
        else:
            step = step + np.random.randint(1,7)
        if np.random.rand() <= 0.001 : # There's a 0.1% chance I fall and have to start at 0
            step = 0
        random_walk.append(step)
    all_walks.append(random_walk)

# Create and plot np_aw_t
np_aw_t = np.transpose(np.array(all_walks))

# Select last row from np_aw_t: ends
ends = np_aw_t[-1,:]

# Plot histogram of ends, display plot
plt.hist(ends,bins=10,edgecolor='k',alpha=0.65)
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.xlabel("Floor")
plt.ylabel("# of times in floor")
plt.show()
```

Comment: [Fitting a Normal distribution to 1D data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011122/fitting-a-normal-distribution-to-1d-data) I hope you find this answer helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.stats.norm` to get a normal distribution. Documentation for it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html). To fit any function to a data set you can use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()`, documentation for that [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). My suggestion would be something like the following:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Making a figure with two y-axis (one for the hist, one for the pdf)
#An alternative would be to multiply the pdf by the sum of counts if you just want to show the fit.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
twinx = ax.twinx()

rands = ss.norm.rvs(loc = 1, scale = 1, size = 1000)

#hist returns the bins and the value of each bin, plot to the y-axis ax
hist = ax.hist(rands)
vals, bins = hist[0], hist[1]

#calculating the center of each bin
bin_centers = [(bins[i] + bins[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(bins)-1)]

#finding the best fit coefficients, note vals/sum(vals) to get the probability in each bin instead of the count
coeff, cov = opt.curve_fit(ss.norm.pdf, bin_centers, vals/sum(vals), p0 = [0,1] )

#loc and scale are mean and standard deviation i believe
loc, scale = coeff

#x-values to plot the normal distribution curve
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 100)

#Evaluating the pdf with the best fit mean and std
p = ss.norm.pdf(x, loc = loc, scale = scale)

#plot the pdf to the other axis and show
twinx.plot(x,p)
plt.show()
```

There are likely more elegant ways to do this, but if you are new to python and are going to use it for calculations and such, getting to know `curve_fit` and `scipy.stats` is recomended. I'm not sure I understand whan you mean by "defining the Randels", hist will plot a "standard" histogram with bins on the x-axis and the count in each bin on the y-axis. When using these counts to fit a pdf we can just divide all the counts by the total number of counts.

Hope that helps, just ask if anything is unclear :)

Edit: compact version

```
vals, bins,_ = ax.hist(my_histogram_data)
bin_centers = [(bins[i] + bins[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(bins)-1)]
coeff, cov = opt.curve_fit(ss.norm.pdf, bin_centers, vals/sum(vals), p0 = [0,1] )
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 100)
p = ss.norm.pdf(x, loc = coeff[0], scale = coeff[1])
#p is now the fitted normal distribution
```

Comment: I tried your code and it indeed plots a norm dist over the histogram. However, is there a way to just fit a norm dist over my existing histogram? I think I've seen it before in R. How does one fit a nom dist based on a given histogram? Also, sorry about the confusion, what I meant is that if you run my code, you will see the x-axis going to 140, but I limited the range to range(100), so why do I see values above it?

Comment: This is the way i would fit a normal pdf to a histogram (just replace the list "rand" with your data). R is optimized for statistics, so you can't expect python to be as perfect for that kind of job (although there is probably a library for it that i just havent found yet). The part of the code that does the fitting is just 3 lines, edited now to a compact version as well. 
The x-axis goes up to the highest value in ends unless you use `plt.xlim()` to cut it off, so the explanation for that has to do with calculating the walks.

Comment: I ran it with your code now, and noticed that you will get a very poor fit with only 10 bins (as you only get 10 data points), so maybe consider running `hist()` with more bins when you want to generate points for your fit (≈100) gave me a good fit. Then run it one more time to generate your plot.