# How to get maximum loglikelihood in python and fit parameters of a normal distribution and a t-student?

Tags: python, scipy, regression, statsmodels, mle

I am working in python and I have some performance data of some actions

DailyReturn = [0.325, -0.287, ...]

I've been trying to fit a normal distribution and a student's t-distribution to the density histogram of that data to use as a PDF. I would like to get the adjustment parameters, the standard errors of the parameters and the value of the LogLikelihood by the method of MLE (maximum likelihood). But I have run into some issues. At the moment I have this idea

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import statistics
def llnorm(par, data):
    n = len(data)
    mu, sigma = par
    ll = -np.sum(-n/2*math.log(2*math.pi*(sigma**2))-((data-mu)**2)/(2*(sigma**2)))
    return ll
data = DailyReturn
result = optimize.minimize(llnorm, [statistics.mean(data),statistics.stdev(data)], args = (data)
```

But I'm not sure and I'm lost with the t student distribution, is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html?highlight=scipy%20stats#module-scipy.stats) you find several distributions, amongn them [student's T](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html?highlight=t%20student) and [normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html?highlight=stats%20norm#scipy.stats.norm)

These modules have a [fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) method. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20011122/12750353) for normal distribution.

Your approach seems to be correct to normal distribution, I there is no point in this case since the optimal solution will be given by the `mu` and `sigma` you are passing.